# Is the order appear on `should` impact query result?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 6.8 and below is a sample of query I send:

```
{
"query": {
   ...
   "bool": {
     "should": [
  { match_phrase: { descriptor: 'xxx' } },
  { match_phrase: { descriptor: 'xxx' } },
  { match_phrase: { descriptor: 'xxx' } },
  { match_phrase: { descriptor: 'xxx' } }
]
}
...
}
```

As you can see there are many `match_phrase` under `should` array. Is the order of these match matter in terms of scores in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter parameter indicates filter context. Its term and range clauses are used in filter context. They will filter out documents which do not match, but they **WILL NOT** affect the score for matching documents.

Please also see the document of ElasticSearch as a reference.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

Comment: The question asks about the "should" array, which is different than the "filter" and it does affect scoring.